# React not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I'm new to react technology and everything was going fine...last time i've checked my react project and it was like 2 days ago (to be more precise its like a tutorial) everything was like it was suppose to be and a React page was working fine. After the weekend, I continue the tutorial I was doing and when I check the page React was doing, its like an old tutorial step. I've already check it all and in an act of despair I've also cleaned up browser cache/history you name it.

This is my component:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const list = [
  {
    title: 'React',
    url: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/',
    author: 'Jordan Walke',
    num_comments: 3,
    points: 4,
    objectID: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Redux',
    url: 'https://github.com/reactjs/redux',
    author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
    num_comments: 2,
    points: 5,
    objectID: 1,
  },
];

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const helloWorld = 'Welcome to React PAH';
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {list.map(function (item){
          return(
                  <div key={item.objectID}>
                    <span>
                      <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                    </span>
                    <span>{item.author}</span>
                    <span>{item.num_comments}</span>
                    <span>{item.points}</span>
                  </div>
                  );
        })}
        <h2>{helloWorld}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
        
export default App;
```

And I'm including this component using another JavaScript file that does:

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
        );

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}
```

I already confirmed that my html page has an `id` = `root`, so that's not the problem (or so I think). The page that it's rendering to me is like:

[Image of what React is rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmwam.png)[image]

Does anyone knows what's happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? What's not updating/working? Be more specific please.

Comment: As you can see my App component was suppose to render some info about variable list and only then an "Welcome to React" but whats happening you can see in the image I've posted in the original question

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but have you saw the image I've uploaded? I appreciate the help but I think you're not understanding the question. I'll try anyway your solution and will shortly give feedback ;) Thanks

Comment: Yes, I saw it. You're not getting the data from your `list` printed.

Comment: @Chris, it still does not work :s It's showing the same page over and over again, it doesn't matter what I change in the component. Yes, it's true, the component was already like the render It's showing, but it was a long time ago. It's showing over and over again the same thing

Comment: And you're sure you are compiling also?

Comment: Last time I've made changes to the component and I put that variable outside the component it did render just fine, but now it's showing some old info. I'm using npm btw

Comment: What are you using to compile your React app?

Comment: @Chris how can I check if its compiling? In the start it was doing real time changes, I just needed to save the file and the browser would have the changes. Now, even if I close/F5 the browser, it's always showing the same thing

Comment: You have to do it manually through your Terminal/Command Line. I personally use Gulp, but perhaps you use another tool for that. I'm guessing that the tutorial you followed had you run a `Watch` command, which automatically compiles anytime you save a change on your code. When you took a break from the tutorial you probably closed the terminal which stopped the Watch. I suggest watching your tutorial again and find the point where they tell you how to compile.

Comment: As I said, I'm new and I don't know much about that. I know I'm using npm so I can run react, but I'll search a little more about compiling it then. Thanks

Comment: No worries. It looks like you need to watch that tutorial again because you've missed a few points on how it all works. :)

Comment: I've not even finished it. I open the project to resume the tutorial. The last time I was using it, everything was fine and like it suppose to be (according to the tutorial I got). Today, as I start the tutorial and run "npm start" so I could see the html/react page, it looks like it froze at some old step. Lets say that I've finished the tutorial at step 5 and so far it was good. Today, for some reason, the page its showing it's like on the step 2